# Jelastic - Glassfish and PostgreSQL cloudlets needed

Tags: postgresql, resources, glassfish, jelastic

Since I'm getting close to deploying my app on Jelastic, I've started thinking about how many cloudlets I should use.

I know Jelastic is quite... elastic when it comes to pricing and I won't be charged for resources I don't use, still I'd like to know what kind of resources my environment needs.

It's really simple, Glassfish 4 and Postgresql.

Initially, I assigned 2 reserved cloudlets to GF and 4 to scale. I saw a doc about GF3 and changed it to 5 reserved and 7 with admin panel open.

For Postgresql, I have 2 and 4 cloudlets respectively.

Are these numbers any good? Considering I'll have no more than 10 users daily (let alone simultaneously), do these cloudlets make sense?

Comment: Feel free to try your consumption with minimum reserved and some supply in scalable for some time. After that, you will really know the consumption of your particular environment with your project and can tune cloudlets according to collected data. More details https://docs.jelastic.com/consumed-resources

Comment: It very much depends what is inside your app. But in general your numbers look fine for a small project, just make sure you have enabled OOM Killer alerts http://blog.jelastic.com/2017/06/07/oom-killer-for-automatic-memory-cleaning/. If you face performance issues you can always adjust the cloudlets later w/o project redeploy.

Comment: That link is very useful, actually I understood now what some icons mean :P I'll check that Killer alerts functionality, seems quite nice. Thanks all!